# How do I use serialization to save a gamestate using multiple classes?

Tags: java, serialization

For a project I am involved in, I have the task of writing some code to be able to save and load the current gamestate. Now, being that I am using java, I already know *Serialization* is probably the best way to go about this. Now, the gamestate that I have to save involves one main class witha singleton pattern shown here:

```
public class Game implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private static ArrayList<Room> world;
    private static Game game = nul

    private Game(){}

    public static Game getGame()
    {
        if (game != null)
        {
            game = new Game();
        }
        return game;
    }
```

A little bit further down in the code are a bunch of objects that are used to help the game run.

```
    Position heroPos = new Position(HERO_ROOM_INDEX,
                                        HERO_POS_X, HERO_POS_Y);
    Rectangle heroHitbox = new Rectangle(
                            new Position(HERO_ROOM_INDEX, 
                                HERO_HITBOX_X_OFFSET, HERO_HITBOX_Y_OFFSET),
                            HERO_HITBOX_WIDTH,
                            HERO_HITBOX_HEIGHT);
    Entity hero = new Player(heroPos, heroHitbox, HERO_SYMBOL);

    Position leverPos = new Position(getPlayerRoomIndex(), LEVER_POS_X, 
                                LEVER_POS_Y);
```

(The actual code is pretty long and would be hard to read, but it follows mostly the same format)

Where *Entity*, *Rectangle*, *Position* are all separate classes in different packages than *Game*. So, if I were to try and serialize this *Game* object, how would I go about it? Would I have to use *ObjectOutputStream* to write every single object that *Game* creates into a file? Or do I just have to make sure that all of these classes that *Game* uses implement the *Serializable* interface, and then just serialize the *Game* object?

Comment: `"Now, being that I am using java, I already know Serialization is probably the best way to go about this."` -- are you 100% sure about this?

Comment: But if you were to use serialization, you'd probably just serialize the game's model, an object that would hold the state of your game's non-view element objects.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Now i'm not! My project lead told me that Serialization was probably the best way to go.

Comment: I've found Java serialization to be tricky and fidgety. Myself, I like to use databases where needed, or if I need to serialize to file, then use text-readable serialization of some sort such as XML/JAXB or JSON. YMMV.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So what exactly would Java Serialization cause a problem with? I'm just wondering because i'm not at all familiar with XML or any of those other things, and was really hoping Serialization would be a viable solution. I'm quickly learning saving a complex game state is a little bit more hard than i thought it would be :/

Comment: For your application, it would probably work OK. Problems of any Java serialization include changing versions of the serialized object, meaning it can be difficult to keep the format "stable", and not presenting the serialized data in a text-readable format. For more advantages and disadvantages, please have a look at [this related software engineering stackexchange post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191269/java-serialization-advantages-and-disadvantages-use-or-avoid).